# How to do conditional check express-validator 5.3.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

```
export function valUPM() {
  return (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    req
      .checkBody(
        "paymentType",
        `paymentType: ${messages.getFromSession(req, "mustNotBeEmpty")}`
      )
      .notEmpty();
    if (req.body.paymentType === "USP") {
      req
        .checkBody(
          "storeId",
          `storeId: ${messages.getFromSession(req, "mustNotBeEmpty")}`
        )
        .notEmpty();
    } else if (req.body.paymentType === "CC") {
      if (req.body.register) {
        req
          .checkBody(
            "register",
            `register: ${messages.getFromSession(req, "mustBeBoolean")}`
          )
          .isBoolean();
      } else {
        req
          .checkBody(
            "register",
            `register: ${messages.getFromSession(req, "mustNotBeEmpty")}`
          )
          .notEmpty();
      }
    }
    req.getValidationResult().then(errs => {
      if (errs.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
      }
      const error = new BFFError(
        400,
        "BadRequest",
        1,
        errs.array().map(error => {
          return { [error.param]: error.msg };
        })
      );
      return next(Error(JSON.stringify(error)));
    });
  };
}
```

After the change to API how to implement this type of logic in express validators

Calling req.checkBody or the required validation function inside an if loop did the trick like shown above but after change in API how can this be implemented 
I tried a work around of checking the paymentTYpe as a custom validator and implementing the checks and throwing the message inside the custom validator but the keys change .

Using the current APi what is the proper way to do this as this will be useful for all the people who would want to update from 3.0.0s to latest express-validator API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional validation support is not present *yet* in express-validator `v5.x.x`, but it is coming *soon*.
Here's the Pull Request, in case you would like to give your feedback on the API: https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/pull/658

However, please note that the legacy API (the one that uses `req.checkBody()`, `req.getValidationResult()`, etc, hasn't been removed from express-validator yet.

You *can* keep using it in `v5.x.x` just as you would in `v3.x.x`. It's just not recommended to do so, as it's deprecated and might be removed when v6 is due (not yet!).

All docs are [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/legacy-api.html), side by side with the newer APIs docs.

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I'm an express-validator maintainer.</sup>

Comment: Am happy to get a feedback directly from a the repo maintainer itself actually I had seen that pull request myself but wanted to be sure cause right now I am in situation where I have to update the validator and for now I used a custom validator and some nested if elses to recreate the earlier conditional validator but I wanted to know if there is any proper or elegant way to do it

Comment: How far long is it from release

Comment: @codefreaK there's no set deadline. I get up to 2 hours a week to work on my OSS projects. It's not much.